# How to use EthernetManager in Xamarin Android API 19?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to make EthernetManager work in Xamarin Android API 19 to use its 
getSavedConfig and updateDevInfo(EthernetDevInfo info) methods, as found here:

ftp://ftp1.digi.com/support/temp/digi-docs/reference/android/net/ethernet/ethernetmanager.html

For this I am using reflection:

```
Java.Lang.Object ethMn = GetSystemService("ethernet");
IntPtr eth0 = JNIEnv.FindClass("android/net/ethernet/EthernetManager");
IntPtr method = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(eth0, "getState", "(V)I");
IntPtr obj = JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod(ethMn.Handle, method);
```

Using getState method above to simplify the invocation.

There is a JNI example here: 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/12117/how-to-get-class-method-by-reflection

and a JNI reference here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/working_with_jni/

The first 2 lines of my code snippet run fine i.e. the system service and class are retrieved into ethMn and e. However the 3rd lines throws an exception saying:

```
Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='getState' signature='(V)I' in class Landroid/net/ethernet/EthernetManager;
```

This is odd because as can be seen from the first link I posted, getState() does exist and with the signature as entered.

I know I am missing something basic, but can't figure out exactly what. Can anyone please help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon the `EthernetManager` on your device, if there even is one, there are *lots* of variants since this is not a public class.

But your signature should be `()I`.

i.e.:

```
m = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(e, "getState", "()I");
```

or (`getEthState` is a common variant of `getState`)

```
m = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(e, "getEthState", "()I");
```

Comment: @zalenix Then you might want to use some Java and get the `GetDeclaredMethods` on the version of the `EthernetManager` class that is on your device,